# How to get the equality?

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

How to get the equality 1,2,3 in picture below .$M$ is compact Riemannian manifold, i,e, $\partial\Omega=\varnothing$.

In fact ,I have a relaxed compute about there 3 equality.I just want see the standard version.

> [image]

Comment: 1 might have something to do w/ f. 2 looks like reverse product rule 3  what is that, inner product?

Comment: @BCLC  1 should use Stokes theorem. Besides, it's inner, this is integral in Riemannian manifold.

Comment: These are all just integration by parts, i.e. product rule + divergence/Stokes theorem.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis  I compute the equality 1 in answer below.Could you help me to check it ? Thanks.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis I think the 3 and 2 use same way, but I can't make out.

Comment: For the second equality, start with the second line and pull out the $\nabla_j$. You get two terms - in one it differentiates the $v$, in the other it differentiates the $e^{-f}$. For the third, start with the LHS $\int \nabla_i f \nabla_i h e^{-f}$ and move the derivative off the $h$.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis  I have added the answer of equality 2 to the below answer, is it right?

Comment: Yes, that's all good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the equality 1, 
$$
\int_M\nabla_i(e^{-f}\nabla_jv_{ij})dV=\int_M e^{-f}\nabla_i(\nabla_jv_{ij})dV-\int_Me^{-f}\nabla_if\nabla_jv_{ij}dV
$$
then,let$F=\{e^{-f}\nabla_jv_{1j},...,e^{-f}\nabla_jv_{nj}\}$,so,
$$
\int_M\nabla_i(e^{-f}\nabla_jv_{ij})dV=\int_M\nabla \cdot F dV=\int_{\partial M}
F\cdot dS=0
$$
So, I can get the equality 1.

About the equality 2,
$$
\int_M(\nabla_if\nabla_jv_{ij}-v_{ij}\nabla_if\nabla_jf)e^{-f}dV
=\int_M\nabla_if(e^{-f}\nabla_jv_{ij}+v_{ij}\nabla_je^{-f})dV
=\int_M\nabla_if(\nabla_j(e^{-f}v_{ij}))dV
$$
then,
$$
0=\int_M\nabla_j(e^{-f}v_{ij}\nabla_if)dV
=\int_m e^{-f}v_{ij}\nabla_i\nabla_jfdV
+\int_M\nabla_if(\nabla_j(e^{-f}v_{ij}))dV
$$
So, the equality 2 is right